# Can someone tell me where the numbers disappear?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Why does following code print 11238 and not 11235?

```
num_list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
for i in range(5):
    print(num_list[num_list[i]])
```

And 13 is not in index 5 why? Where do 5 and 13 disappear?

Comment: Umm... `print(num_list[i])`?

Comment: Yes  it works properly with your code and i know it but where does 5 and 13 go if i use print (num_list[num_list[i]]) and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop says:

```
print (num_list[num_list[0]])
print (num_list[num_list[1]])
print (num_list[num_list[2]])
print (num_list[num_list[3]])
print (num_list[num_list[4]])
```

That means:

```
print (num_list[1]) # since num_list[0] holds 1
print (num_list[1]) # since num_list[1] holds 1
print (num_list[2]) # since num_list[2] holds 2
print (num_list[3]) # since num_list[3] holds 3
print (num_list[5]) # since num_list[4] holds 5
```

which means:

```
print (1) # since num_list[1] holds 1
print (1) # since num_list[1] holds 1
print (2) # since num_list[2] holds 2
print (3) # since num_list[3] holds 3
print (8) # since num_list[5] holds 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and simple answer..

Answer (score 0):

Because You are passing the result of `num_list[i]` as an index to `num_list` thus at the end of your loop `num_list[4] == 5` and `num_list[5] == 8`.

Note that `range(5)` will produce the numbers from `0` to `4`.

If You want to print the first 5 number of your list as the most pythonic way you can use a simple slicing:

```
>>> print(num_list[:5])
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Or use unpacking to print them out of the brackets :

```
>>> print(*num_list[:5])
1 1 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is wrong, if you are expecting 11235 as a result.
it should be like this:

```
num_list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
for i in range(5):
print (num_list[i])
```

Looping on `(num_list[num_list[i]])` will give you :
`num_list[1]`, `num_list[1]`,`num_list[2]`, `num_list[3]` and **`num_list[5]`**(which is **equal to 8**)